# Admin-on-rest left navigation submenu

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-design, material-ui

I'm new in ReactJS and admin-on-rest. I'm learning from [this](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest) documentation and I want to make navigation submenu like [this](http://www.material-ui.com/#/get-started/installation). I searched in google but not found. Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Review the [documentation on menus](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Admin.html#menu):

> Admin-on-rest uses the list of  components passed as children of  to build a menu to each resource with a list component.
>
> If you want to add or remove menu items, for instance to link to non-resources pages, you can create your own menu component.